Confidence interval for difference between means
I have the following information about data:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{12}x_i=2114; \;\sum_{i=1}^{12}y_i=2144;\;\sum_{i=1}^{12}x_i^2=373160;\;\sum_{i=1}^{12}y_i^2=383666$$
And I want to calculate the confidence interval for the difference between $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ with $c=0.95$ assuming that $X-Y$ is a normal random variable. The margin error would be :
$$t_{(22,0.975)}\sqrt{s_p^2(1/12+1/12)}=6.628$$
But I guess that this value is much higher than the expected one (I obtained $s_p^2=61.288, t_{(22,0.975)}=2.0739)$
